# PHP creating multidimensional json

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

There's simple json

```
{"level1_level2_blah": "some value", "level1_level_2 ... _level9999_blah": "hello world"}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to convert it to json like that:

```
{"level1": {"level2": {"blah": "some value"}, ... }}}
```

The number of dimensions (levels) is dynamic. I tried using **dynamic variables'** names, **building single-element json string - decoding it - merging.** I think these methods to be really awful but I didn't find any other ways to do that. It would be ok but these methods didn't even work correctly.

Comment: Do you create the first JSON yourself? If yes you should start at the root and fix it there.

Comment: @roland-starke not exactly. It's an auto-generated single-dimensional json (key-value, key-value...) and it can't be controlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recursively add items to the resulting multidimensional array. Like this:

```
$output = [];
$input = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'a_b_c' => 'test',
    'a_b_d' => 'foo',
    'bar_foo' => 'taz',
    'a_x_y_z_xiv' => '99',
    'bar_bar_bar_bar_bar_bar_bar' => 'foo',
    'a_b_e' => 'bar'
];
function add_to_array(&$array, $key, $value) {
    if (is_array($key) && sizeof($key) > 1) {
        $keyPart = array_shift($key);
        if (!array_key_exists($keyPart, $array)) {
            $array[$keyPart] = [];
        }
        add_to_array($array[$keyPart], $key, $value);
    } else {
        $array[is_array($key)?$key[0]:$key] = $value;
    }
}

foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    add_to_array($output, explode('_', $key), $value);    
}
echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), PHP_EOL;
```

Results in

```
{
    "foo": "tar",
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": "test",
            "d": "foo",
            "e": "bar"
        },
        "x": {
            "y": {
                "z": {
                    "xiv": "99"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "bar": {
        "foo": "taz",
        "bar": {
            "bar": {
                "bar": {
                    "bar": {
                        "bar": {
                            "bar": "foo"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```